# How to remove the info tag from VRPanorama View in android

Tags: android, google-vr, 360-panorama-viewer

I have been trying to work on Google VR SDK for android. I have been successful in implementing the sample. But the info tag on the bottom of the panoramic view widget looks bad for design in release version for my app. So can anybody let me know if it's possible to remove the info tag on the bottom of the view? If yes then please help me out on this.

[image: This is the sample I am running]

Comment: I got this link where it has the answer to my query for now. https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/9#issuecomment-208993643

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove info button from `VrPanoramaView`. `VrPanoramaView` extends `VrWidgetView`.

`VrWidgetView` has method `setInfoButtonEnabled(boolean value)` in which you can either show or remove info button. call method like this:

```
panoWidgetView.setInfoButtonEnabled(false);
```

where `panoWidgetView` is instance of `VrPanoramaView`.